# rome.js value change callback?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have this datetime picker with [rome.js](https://github.com/bevacqua/rome). 
I'm looking for a callback whenever I pick a new date. According to the documentation, these types of events emit using a library named `contra`. However, I am on the client side, so node.js doesn't really work. How do I subscribe to these events?

Comment: Just use Browserify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason you'd need node for this: node comes with the EventEmitter utility built-in, but it's perfectly possible to implement an event emitter outside of node, which is exactly what the `contra` library has done.

The following code will run fine in the browser:

```
var datePicker = rome(element, romeOptions);
datePicker.on('data', (newDate) => {
    //
});
```